# Method runs in separate thread - how to retrieve its value in calling thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have method that return some data type

```
MyType MyMethod()
```

If I am running this method into a separate thread, how can this return type be retrieve in the calling thread (that invokes other thread executing MyMethod)?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, here's one:

```
Func<MyType> func = MyMethod;
func.BeginInvoke(ar =>
{
    MyType result = (MyType)func.EndInvoke(ar);
    // Do something useful with result
    ...
},
null);
```

Here's another, using the `Task` API:

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(new Func<MyType>(MyMethod))
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        MyType result = task.Result;
        // Do something useful with result
        ...
    });
```

And a last one, using the Async CTP (preview of C# 5):

```
MyType result = await Task.Factory.StartNew<MyType>(MyMethod);
// Do something useful with result
...
```

Comment: I'd recommend going the Task route in .Net 4. It's the newer, easier way of running concurrent processes. Like many of the "pillars" of .Net 3+, the focus is on making code more declarative, describing *what* it wants, and leaving the details of *how* to do it up to the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think IAsyncResult pattern is your best bet.  You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879163/what-is-a-proper-implementation-of-the-iasyncresult-interface).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest is to have both threads read from/write to the same static variable.

This thread, while slightly different, also has some ideas: [How to share data between different threads In C# using AOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360533/how-to-share-data-between-different-threads-in-c-using-aop)